# Is it possible to change the default redirect message in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using a controller to redirect my users after they have changed the website's language.

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($_redirectTo), 301);
```

The problem is, that the message "redirecting to /path/" shows up, which i don't want to. 
Is it possible to change that message?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method [`Controller::redirect()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_redirect) is in fact, creating a new [`RedirectResponse`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html) object.
The default template is [hard-coded](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.php#L88) into the response but here are some workarounds.

> *In this example, I will use a TWIG template, hence I need the `@templating` service, but you can use whatever you want to render the page.*

First, create your template `301.html.twig` into your `Acme/FooBundle/Resources/views/Error/` with the content you want.

<kbd>**@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/views/Error/301.html.twig**</kbd>

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url={{ uri }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        You are about to be redirected to {{ uri }}
    </body>
</html>
```

## From an event listener

If you want this template to be global on any `RedirectResponse` you can create an event listener which will listen to the response and check whether the response given is an instance of `RedirectResponse`
This means that you can still use `return $this->redirect` in your controller, only the content of the response will be affected.

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    acme.redirect_listener:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Listener\RedirectListener
        arguments: [ @templating ]
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: kernel.response
                method: onKernelResponse
```

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\Listener\RedirectListener**</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class RedirectListener
{
    protected $templating;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        if (!($response instanceof RedirectResponse)) {
            return;
        }

        $uri  = $response->getTargetUrl();
        $html = $this->templating->render(
            'AcmeFooBundle:Error:301.html.twig',
            array('uri' => $uri)
        );

        $response->setContent($html);
    }
}
```

## From a controller

Use this if you want to change the template directly from an action.
The modification will only be available for the given action, not global to your application.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function fooAction()
    {
        $uri = $this->generateUrl($_redirectTo);

        $response = new RedirectResponse($uri, 301);
        $response->setContent($this->render(
            'AcmeFooBundle:Error:301.html.twig',
            array( 'uri' => $uri )
        ));

        return $response;
    }
}
```