# Symfony2 - disable "redirecting to" message

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

Is there anyway I could disable that message:

```
"Redirecting to {url}"
```

Or even that whole page with `http-equiv="refresh"`?

It looks like after login and logout actions, Symfony calls `createRedirectResponse` method and it creates `RedirectResponse` object which creates that funny html page.

It would be great if it could be just simple Redirect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the default redirect message in Symfony?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205039/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-redirect-message-in-symfony)

Comment: @Mr.Smith I didn't saw that, removing mine.

Comment: @HeroFTime So did you figure it out ?