# Redirecting in Symfony2 without showing the message

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, nginx

I'm redirecting from inside a controller doing

```
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("member_editProfile"));
```

But this shows a message : `Redirecting to ...` for a couple of seconds before redirecting. I'm looking for a way to remove this message.

I found this message hardcoded in `\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse.php`
But when I `$this->setContent('');` (inside the file, method setTargetUrl()) or when I remove the `$this->setContent();` line, the redirection is broken, no error is thrown but redirection is not working.

I've also tried doing:

```
$response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('member_editProfile'));
$response->setContent('');
return $response;
```

Same issue there.

So to summarize, I'm looking for a way to redirect without showing any message.

PS: I'm using Nginx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the default redirect message in Symfony?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205039/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-redirect-message-in-symfony)

Comment: @LéoLam Not really, as the other ticket is about changing the message template not hiding it..

Comment: You could hide it simply by using an empty message template, or an invisible message.

Comment: @LéoLam as I mentioned in the details, using an empty string doing $this->setContent(' '); or even deleting the line result in redirection not working.

Comment: Yes, but have you tried the method in the question I linked to with an empty message, or maybe with an invisible message (with invisible spaces/characters) if that doesn't work?