# Symfony2 RedirectResponse message

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have problem with redirect to another website. When I redirected I see message: "Redirecting to...". Why? Really I can't redirect to site without problem?

I see:
[Is it possible to change the default redirect message in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205039/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-redirect-message-in-symfony)

My code:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/project/{url}/{link}/", name="page_show")
   * @Template("base.html.twig")
   */
  public function pageAction($link, $url) {

    if ($link == '...') {
      $redrect = new RedirectResponse('http://...');
      return $redrect;
    }
```

Maybe I'm Idiot and don't see solution...

Comment: What you posted looks like it should work just fine.  Are you sure your redirect url is correct?  What happens is you copy/paste it into a browser?

Comment: URL is correct. I see the message and then I was redirected

Comment: All I can think of is that you have some sort of listener intercepting this or maybe your host has some sort of restriction going on.  I would make a simple redirect.php file with a simple http redirect in it just to rule out any host mysteries. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Ok. Maybe it help. It is system for creating simple website. Subdomain is redirecting to my server through CURL. /project/url, project is name website, url is address. Example: /xyz.google.com/contact. Now I do double redirect... First redirect to my serwer, second redirect to another serwer. Symfony2 may have a problem...

Comment: Doubtful.  S2 pretty much works as designed.  More likely a web server config issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can combine `@Template("base.html.twig")` with a redirect response. Try to remove the `@template` annotation and do a render of base.html.twig in the end of your action :

```
/**
 * @Route("/project/{url}/{link}/", name="page_show")
 */
public function pageAction($link, $url) {

    if ($link == '...') {
      $redrect = new RedirectResponse('http://...');
      return $redrect;
    }

    // Maybe add the proper path "BundleName:DirectoryName:base.html.twig"
    return $this->render('base.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: I thought that it is solution. Of course doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Read closely

> First, create your template 301.html.twig into your Acme/FooBundle/Resources/views/Error/ with the content you want.

Here:
[Is it possible to change the default redirect message in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205039/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-redirect-message-in-symfony)

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to Another web site:

```
public function pageAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->redirect('https://google.com');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening in the **development environment**, then you have set the `intercept_redirects` configuration option to `true`. Set it to `false` as explained in: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html

If this is happening in the **production environment**, the reason is that `RedirectResponse` has some hardcoded HTML content to do the redirection. See these lines of code: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.php#L86-L96

During 1 second, you see the *Redirecting to ...* message. Changing this message is possible, but it requires you a lot of effort. Everything is explained here: [Is it possible to change the default redirect message in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205039/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-redirect-message-in-symfony)

---

Update: in [this discussion in the Symfony repository](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17824#issuecomment-185251239) there is more information about this. The redirect should be instantaneous because it should use the information provided in the response headers. If something wrong happens, then the hardcoded HTML content is used. So you probably need to debug why the response is not getting the right redirect headers.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is in official Symfony book.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting

```
public function pageAction()
{
   return $this->redirect('http://stackoverflow.com');
}
```

Comment: Which of course if you look at the base controller code is identical to what he is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are really keen to redirect using the Symfony' RedirectResponse class, you can always relay on the old good PHP:

```
function redirectUrl($url, $replace=true, $status=302){
    header("Location : ".$url, $replace, $status);
    exit();
}

// usage example
redirectUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

This not only works like a charm but is extremely fast in comparison with Symfony's internal function because there is only one call + die/exit.

Read more about the PHP's [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

However, since this approach is totally decoupled from the framework, the Symfony profiler won't be able to intercept your redirect so the developer toolbar won't notice/show this redirect. It depends what you want.